# Преобразование строкового вектора в числовой в R

Tags: r

Допустим, есть вектор `a <- c("1,2" , "3,6" , "4,9", "9,1")`

Хочу преобразовать его в числовой и записать в вектор n:

`n<- as.numeric(s)`

Но на выходе получаю вектор с пропущенными значениями:

```
Предупреждение:
в результате преобразования созданы NA 

[1] NA NA NA NA
```

Проверка типа данных показывает, что вектор типа numeric, как и надо. Но как все-таки вывести на экран числа, а не эти на-на-на..?

Answer (score 3):

проблема у вас тут в том, что для разделения целой и дробной части используется символ `,` вместо `.`, которая, вероятно, определена как разделитель («decimal_mark») в используемой вами локали.

если у вас нет возможности изменить использованный разделитель в ваших данных, то, не меняя локаль (или хотя бы «decimal_mark» в существующей), пожалуй, самым надёжным и простым из [способов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15236440/4827341) в данном случае будет использование функции `scan()` вместо `as.numeric()`:

```r
a <- c("1,2" , "3,6" , "4,9", "9,1")
scan(text=a, dec=',')
#> [1] 1.2 3.6 4.9 9.1
```

но более быстрым решением будет замена `,` на `.` «на лету» с помощью функции `sub()`:

```r
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", a, fixed = TRUE))
#> [1] 1.2 3.6 4.9 9.1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>